# If all result equals, return true

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a simple select that returns a single column:

> result: {1,1,2}

I want to check if all result are 1 then return true and if one column have a 2 return false.

Tried something like these:

```
SELECT IF(items.status=1, 'true', 'false') AS result
FROM bd.items 
WHERE items.id=33
```

But obviously it returns true if a value is 1 and false if it is 2, instead of just one result.

For example:

> {1,1,1}=true

> {1,2,1}=false

> {1}=true

> {2}=false

Comment: *if all result are 1 then return true and if one column have a 2 return false.* Think backward - if at least one row has value 2 then false else true. If 1 and 2 are the only possible values then it is enough to check MAX(value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select min(status = 1) as result
from bd.items
where id = 33
```

This returns `1` if and only if all rows have `status` `1`. If there is any other (non-`null`) value in the column, then this returns `0`.

If you want this for all items at once:

```
select id, min(status = 1) as result
from bd.items
group by id
```

Comment: The other answers works as well, but for now I'll be using this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```sql
select 
case 
when (max(items.status)=min(items.status) and min(items.status)=1) 
then 'True' else 'False' end
from items
where items.id=33
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use next approach:

```
select 
    id, count(status) = count(case when status=1 then 1 end) status
from items
group by id
;
```

The query returns true when count all rows equal to count rows with status = 1

This and couple of other queries it [here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=bc125bf7b2a06e9155364bba2abf96b8&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)